# cypher: using `foreach` in `merge … on create`

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My first question on stackoverflow - yeah.

The following query should create a picture if it is not already there. `url`(describes a picture clearly), `title` and `tags`(array) are passed as parameters. Every picture has some tags, represented by nodes. It works but not fast.

```
MERGE (pic:Picture {url:{url}})
ON CREATE
  SET pic.title = {title}, pic.created = timestamp()
  FOREACH (tagname IN {tags} |
    MERGE (t:Tag {name:tagname})
    MERGE (pic)-[:tag]->(t)
  )
```

`set` (line 3) will only be executed if the picture has been created new - fine.

`foreach` (line 4) will be executed in every case - not fine.

Is there any way to solve this problem in one query? I want line 4-7 only to be executed `on create` (line 2) because there is a huge difference in the execution time.

Brackets don't work.

I use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE UNIQUE` because I need `ON CREATE` … and `MERGE` seems to be faster.

I will also be thankful for any further optimizations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jkoschwitz,

You can do this using a temporary property and a WHERE clause. You can also use the UNWIND clause to make this a bit nicer.

```
MERGE (pic:Picture {url:{url}})
ON CREATE
SET pic.title = {title}, pic.created = timestamp(), pic.new = 1
WITH pic
WHERE pic.new = 1
UNWIND {tags} as tagname
MERGE (t:Tag {name : tagname})
MERGE (pic)-[:tag]->(t)
REMOVE pic.new
```

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Thanks a lot! 10 times faster for 2000 pictures that are already in the database. Unfortunately I have not yet enough reputation to vote your answer up. Josua

Answer (score 0):

```
    MERGE (pic:Picture {url:{url}})
    ON CREATE
        SET pic.title = {title}, pic.created = timestamp(), pic.new = 1
        FOREACH (tagname IN CASE WHEN pic.new = 1 THEN {tags} ELSE [] END |
            MERGE (t:Tag {name:tagname})
            MERGE (pic)-[:tag]->(t)
        )
        REMOVE pic.new
```